# Send Grid latest maven has CVE vulnerabilities. How do we tackle?

Tags: java, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Send Grid latest maven has CVE vulnerabilities. How do we tackle?
Is there any other way to send mails using sendgrid without installing their maven dependency?

Comment: Just exclude `log4j` from Maven dependency and there you go.

Comment: @WildDev i dont think its due to log4j, its due to jackson data binding

Comment: Jackson `v2.13.2` uses older `log4j` dependency that's why the build is still vulnerable. See [CVE Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html). You will need to analyze your project dependencies to determine the ones that are up to exclude. This thing would help you with that -> [Intellij's Maven dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#see_structure)

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open pull request to update `jackson-databind`](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/pull/727). If you want that prioritised, the best thing is to comment on and show support for getting the pull request merged.